# Unable to locate publishable resource when adding sanctum to existing project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

The [Laravel Sanctum documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#installation) states that to add Sanctum to existing Laravel project one has to:

1. Require Laravel Sanctum `composer require laravel/sanctum`
2. Publish Sanctum's resources to app dir `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"`

I'm getting `Unable to locate publishable resources.` when running (2)

I already tried `php artisan clear-compiled` and `composer dumpautoload` in that order

I checked that `vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/SanctumServiceProvider.php` exists and the boot() method does publishes Sanctum's config and migration

I also checked that SanctumServiceProvider is discovered by autoload by making sure that the source path is listed in `autoload_classmap.php`

Again, this was an attempt to add Sanctum to an existing Laravel project

Did I miss something?

My setup:

- Laravel 8.37
- PHP 7.3.9
- Composer 2.0.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem.

**Short answer:**

After `composer require laravel/sanctum` do this:

1. Backup or rename `cache/services.php`
2. Remove `cache/services.php`
3. Run `php artisan`. Seems that running artisan in any way will regenerate `cache/services.php`

After that, continue with the official documentation (publish, migrate, and so on)

**Longer explaination**

Not entirely sure what is going on. But apparently all discovered [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers) is cached in `cache/services.php`.

I don't know how it's being generated and how service providers get discovered. Googling doesn't yield me any documentation regarding that file (official or otherwise).

I figured I if I add Sanctum's SP to `config/app.php` (i.e. the documented way of adding service provider) it will get discovered and cached. Apparently that wasn't the case. Removing and regenrating `cache/services.php` is the only way I found working. After the file was regenerated, Sanctum's SP is listed.

One thing I observe was that this only happens on an existing project (existing as in already being worked on, packages added, config changes and so on). Doesn't happen if I add Sanctum to a fresh project.